# getting the rows of the data to limit to 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which returns me data, it can return me same user multiple times if it has one of the column has different values, like if the column have different values as: `contact, email, phone,face`

So I have 4 rows of same user with the one column has different values:

```
id     name         status
1      user1        email
2      user1        phone
3      user1        face
4      user1        contact
```

I want to limit to 2, so in the above case, even I have multiple rows, I see the user has 4 rows, I want it to limited to 2.

I can't use `top` or `limit` because I am using SQL Server and there are other rows which has only 1 row per user because they have only 1 status, so my ultimate question is:

> If the status field has more than 2 rows of same user, just limit it to 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a limit per user, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: what i t in the inner sub query , i do not want use that

Comment: and is order by necessary

Comment: and want to apply only to the column if it has more than 2, if that column is null, it should display the user as many as it is appearing

Comment: @Asum . . . `t` is the name of your table.  The `order by` specifies *which* two rows you get per `name`.  This returns at most two rows per name, regardless of the number of rows in the data.

Comment: what about the null, if there is no value, if the colum is null and user is appearing 4 times, i want it to appear 4 times

Comment: like i have another row who has 4 rows of same user but the status of null, i want those all 4 as is, the condition should be applied if the column has a value and has more than 2

Comment: @Asum please don't change your criteria... if you have edge cases your question doesn't cover, why should you expect an answerer to read your mind about them?

Comment: i missed that piece @AaronBertrand in my question that i need to consider the nulls too, i later realized when i ran it, it did not showed up.